# warning: cannot resolve "python2-audit", a dependency of "selinux-python2" - Arch linux

Tags: python-2.x, archlinux, selinux

Following the guide here to install and use all needed utilities to use SELinux - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SELinux#Installing_SELinux and using the git repo, I get the following error:

```
warning: cannot resolve "python2-audit", a dependency of "selinux-python2"
:: The following package cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable dependencies:
      selinux-python2

:: Do you want to skip the above package for this upgrade? [y/N] 
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: unable to satisfy dependency 'python2-audit' required by selinux-python2
Error: the following command failed, sudo LANG=C pacman --noconfirm --ask=4 -U ./selinux-python/selinux-python2-2.9-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz ./selinux-python/selinux-python-2.9-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

while running ./build_and_install_all.sh

I have the core repo enabled, and have tried refreshing the db repeatedly

Why is it saying that python2-audit is not available, when the wiki says it is available in the core repo?

And unless I can somehow get it installed, can I and how do I bypass that requirement?

Comment: have you tried to install `python2-audit` manually by typing `pacman -S python2-audit` ?

Comment: @C.W. yes, it informs me `target not found`

Comment: do you use the up to date git-repo? For me it is working with the current version of the repo.

Comment: @C.W. Latest one migrated from python so yeah. However refpolicy fails to build with a python syntax error